# mongodb/mongoose protected attribute

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How do I protect an attribute from being mass assigned in mongoose? Like in rails :attr_protected. I tried by prefixing it with an underscore but it's still "assignable"

Answer (score 0):

You could make the attribute a read-only [virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals).

Comment: Virtual attributes are attributes that are convenient to have around but that do not get persisted to MongoDB. I don't care about reads. Writing is the problem here. I don't want to have all fields mass-assignable

Comment: @RomeoMihalcea I don't believe there's any way to do that declaratively in Mongoose.  You'd have to enforce that restriction in server-side code.